# Applying custom shortcut for a shape to the current cell I am on

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a custom shape with a hotkey. I want it to automatically go to a specific cell I am currently on instead of the same area every single time I run it with my hotkey.

```
Sub RedSquareShapeNoFill()
'
' RedSquareShapeNoFill Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 197.25, 44.25, 96.75, 26.25). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1.5
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd parameter of the AddShape command are the top and left  corner of the shape. You need to change these numbers to reflect your current position.

Comment: ^ See the [`AddShape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addshape) documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current selection could be assigned to a range variable. Then, working with that range, one may use the `.Left`, `.Top`, `.Width` and `.Height` properties of the range.

Another good idea is to declare the shape as a variable and work with it and not with the `Selection`, [because it is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) - the selection can be a `Range` or a `Shape` object:

```
Sub RedSquareShapeNoFill()

    Dim myShape As Shape
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim selectionRange As Range
    Set selectionRange = Selection

    Set myShape = wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                selectionRange.Left, _
                selectionRange.Top, _
                selectionRange.Width, _
                selectionRange.Height)

    With myShape.Line
        myShape.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1.5
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the top and left of the current cell and plug that into the AddShape parameters

```
Dim myTop As Double
Dim myLeft As Double
    myTop = Selection.Top
    myLeft = Selection.Left
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, myLeft, myTop, 96.75, 26.25). _
        Select
```

Comment: @BigBen yes, thanks. That would be more accurate. I'll edit it.

Comment: If I wanted to do this for an arrow and I added the same my left and my top parameters how do I make it so the arrow points to a random location or perhaps a fixed length to anywhere on the excel file?